# Cannot read variable data of child view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component `MyComponent` and it is declared like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements IComponent {
    ...
    @Input() Departments: any;    
    @Input() DropDownOptions: any;    
    @Input() Data: any[];
    ...
}
```

However, there is no property `Data`, when I try to access from `PersonComponent` component.

HTML of `PersonComponent` component:

```
<fieldset>
    <my-comp #myGrid [Options]="ps.Options['myGrid']"></my-comp>
</fieldset>
```

TypeScript of `PersonComponent` component:

```
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {    
    @ViewChild('myGrid') myGridComponent: MyComponent;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        debugger;        
        let localData2 = this.myGridComponent.Data; // NO DATA PROPERTY. Undefined

    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        debugger;        
        let localData1 = this.myGridComponent.Data; // NO DATA PROPERTY. Undefined       
    }

}
```

Variables that can be seen at debugger of Chrome:

[image]

How can I read values of `Data` property of `MyComponent`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `@Input() Data` is an Input-decorator, thus you need to provide the data to your component. `<my-comp #myGrid [Options]="ps.Options['gridShipmentHeaders']" [Data]="someData" ></my-comp>`

Comment: data is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Input Data ... decorator "receives" data from the parent component. You set it via the attribute [Data] inside the parent template. If you don't set it it will be indefined. On the other hand you have [Options] attribute that doesn't have the corresponding @Input in the child.

You can fix it like so:

```
<fieldset>
    <my-comp #myGrid [Data]="person.data"></my-comp>
</fieldset>
```

where person is an array with data field in parent component.

Please read thoughtfully the documention https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs and https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

And it would be better to not use reserved/too generic name like Data, Options to avoid name collisions and also camel case them.

Comment: in other words I should send data from `PersonComponent`into `MyComp` to get `[Data]` property at `PersonComponent`?

Comment: From your code logic: yes. But it could be fetch from a service,  etc. But in that case you would not need @Input

Comment: @Input is for parent child communication in your case